# How can I create a self-signed certificate using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, self-signed

I need to create a self-signed certificate (for local encryption - it's not used to secure communications), using C#.

I've seen some implementations that use [P/Invoke](http://www.daveamenta.com/2008-05/what-is-pinvoke-pinvoke/) with [Crypt32.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but they are complicated and it's hard to update the parameters - and I would also like to avoid P/Invoke if at all possible.

I don't need something that is cross platform - running only on Windows is good enough for me.

Ideally, the result would be an X509Certificate2 object that I can use to insert into the Windows certificate store or export to a [PFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) file.

Comment: For future readers, I have posted my BouncyCastle code at : https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2016/11/04/service-bus-and-custom-self-signed-certificates-with-a-high-availabilitymultiple-computing-nodes-in-the-farm/     This will create 2 certs.  One to be the "Trusted Root" certificate and the second one which is "signed" by the (first) Trusted Root certificate.

Comment: It's possible to do this without using COM or external dependencies now, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196350.

Comment: In VS2019:  Project Properties->Signing->ClickOnce->Create Test Certificate?

Comment: @Andrew the question is how to create this programmatically. There are plenty of ways to create a one-use self-signed certificate, such as using CertUtil or openssl, but the context of the question is building software that generates these certs automatically on a user machine.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This implementation uses the `CX509CertificateRequestCertificate` COM object (and friends - [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) from `certenroll.dll` to create a self signed certificate request and sign it.

The example below is pretty straight forward (if you ignore the bits of COM stuff that goes on here) and there are a few parts of the code that are really optional (such as EKU) which are none-the-less useful and easy to adapt to your use.

```
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string subjectName)
{
    // create DN for subject and issuer
    var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
    dn.Encode("CN=" + subjectName, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);

    // create a new private key for the certificate
    CX509PrivateKey privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
    privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
    privateKey.MachineContext = true;
    privateKey.Length = 2048;
    privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE; // use is not limited
    privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
    privateKey.Create();

    // Use the stronger SHA512 hashing algorithm
    var hashobj = new CObjectId();
    hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
        ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY, 
        AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA512");

    // add extended key usage if you want - look at MSDN for a list of possible OIDs
    var oid = new CObjectId();
    oid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"); // SSL server
    var oidlist = new CObjectIds();
    oidlist.Add(oid);
    var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
    eku.InitializeEncode(oidlist); 

    // Create the self signing request
    var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
    cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, privateKey, "");
    cert.Subject = dn;
    cert.Issuer = dn; // the issuer and the subject are the same
    cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now;
    // this cert expires immediately. Change to whatever makes sense for you
    cert.NotAfter = DateTime.Now; 
    cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku); // add the EKU
    cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
    cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

    // Do the final enrollment process
    var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
    enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert); // load the certificate
    enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = subjectName; // Optional: add a friendly name
    string csr = enroll.CreateRequest(); // Output the request in base64
    // and install it back as the response
    enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate,
        csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, ""); // no password
    // output a base64 encoded PKCS#12 so we can import it back to the .Net security classes
    var base64encoded = enroll.CreatePFX("", // no password, this is for internal consumption
        PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainWithRoot);

    // instantiate the target class with the PKCS#12 data (and the empty password)
    return new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
        System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded), "", 
        // mark the private key as exportable (this is usually what you want to do)
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
    );
}
```

The result can be added to a certificate store using `X509Store` or exported using the `X509Certificate2` methods.

For a fully managed and not tied to Microsoft's platform, and if you're OK with Mono's licensing, then you can look at [X509CertificateBuilder](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=hlZXds9VgYcE3MIgdWJfVBrCE-o&cid=oX7t2cSLUiM&s=X509CertificateBuilder&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L2) from [Mono.Security](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography#Assembly:_Mono.Security). Mono.Security is standalone from Mono, in that it doesn't need the rest of Mono to run and can be used in any compliant .Net environment (e.g. Microsoft's implementation).

Comment: You might also point it out that Mono has a fully managed implementation of makecert (powered by Mono.Security as your describe), https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/makecert.cs That serves as a better example if someone wants to explore Mono.

Comment: Where can I get the libraries/assemblies for this?

Comment: @bukko: Please peruse the links in the answer.

Comment: @Guss: sorry I'm obviously a bit slow. I can't use Mono, but the Lightswitch link doesn't describe where to get the library(s) unless I missed it, which is very possible...

Comment: ...or is CertEnroll.dll included in Windows...?

Comment: If you want to use the code sample I posted above, use it in conjunction with `certenroll.dll` which should be available in your operating system (I think Windows 6.0 and above).

Comment: I can't get this to work on Windows 8 :( on the line "enroll.CreateRequest" I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException ...

Comment: I've never used win8, and I'm not familiar with its rather different authorization model (nor do I ever plan to), so I can't help you much in that. Though I'd might check if the cryptographic provider name is OK, or it needs changing for win8.

Comment: @Motig, you need to run as administrator.

Comment: Meanwhile, SHA512 can be problematic as some services might not support it. Should use SHA1 for better compatibility.

Comment: Please note that most people consider SHA1 to be a security problem and deprecated. Specifically Google stated that they will rank down web sites that are still using SHA1, with complete exclusion in the near future. Do not use SHA1 unless you have specific backward compatibility concerns that cannot be resolved otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to get X509Certificate2 with private key without enrollment proccess?

Comment: @a.farkas2508, I'm not sure what you mean by that - "enrollment" is what Microsoft calls the actual process of creating a certificae by signing a request. This is normally done by a CA service, but the above code does it internally with the private key it just generated and immediately drops the enrollment context - so you can say that this is done "without an enrollment process" because it is done completely internally.

Comment: this code actually seems to immediately install the certificate into the LocalMachine\My store. Is that normal? How can I have more control over that?

Comment: @blub: why do you think the certificate is installed in the "my" store? The cert must be installed, because .net doesn't actually holds the private bits in memory (it's not secure) but uses the Windows crypto API, which holds the secret stuff in a certificate store (which is the Right Thing (TM)), but it should be an anonymous store and definetly not the "my" store.

Comment: Guss, I call your code and then click refresh on my mmc.exe snap in "Certificates (Local Computer) / Personal / Certificates" and it shows up there. That's the MY store!

Comment: I put up a version using mono.security at http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/04/creating-self-signed-x-509-certificates-using-mono-security/

Comment: mono makecert.cs is not secure. It generates only with MD5 and SHA1 .. do not use as-is. Modify the code to use SHA512 before generating a certificate.

Comment: @John: correct for Mono.Security's as mentioned by Lex Li - but Freek's implementation uses SHA2.

Comment: Noticed that the answer was edited to correct a mispelled class name `CX500DistinguishedName`, when in fact it is supposed to be CX500 and not X500 in order for the encode method to work and for the object to be assigned to the subject and issuer properties of the CX509CertificateRequestCertificate object.

Comment: You are correct @Hive, I haven't noticed that change. fixed back.

Comment: I'm trying to adopt this to be able to store a self signed certificate that is non-exportable and stored in the user store. afterwards.. So all I did was change  X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine --> ContextUser and set X509PrivateKeyExportFlags to NONE. I get a "CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestCertificate::InitializeFromPrivateKey: The parameter is incorrect. " message if I do. Any help?

Comment: If you get the error:

error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'CERTENROLLLib.IX509PrivateKey' to 'CERTENROLLLib.CX509PrivateKey'

Check out the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35365099/1100379

Comment: how to sign a certificate using bouncy castle, or make CA signed certificates using bouncy castle

Comment: When running above code getting this exception:System.ArithmeticException
  HResult=0x80070216
  Message=CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestCertificate::InitializeFromTemplateName: Arithmetic result exceeded 32 bits. 0x80070216 (WIN32: 534 ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW)
  Source=Microsoft.Hpc.Scheduler.Store
  StackTrace:
   ........

Comment: Hey, I get "This certificate is not valid for code signing" when trying to sign manifest via ClickOnce in VS. It is valid for Assembly signing though. Any reason for it? What should I change to be able to sign manifests?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the code signing EKU to your certificate. It is `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3`. See the sample code in the answer as to how to add an EKU.

Comment: If you get AccessDenied errors, it's because the sample here tries to make a machine certificate, which requires running as Admin.  Swap out the line `cn.InitiatlizeFromPrivateKey` to this and it will work `cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");`

Comment: I am getting ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE error on Chrome clients, when this script is used in Windows Server 2022

Comment: @Sahin - this is very likely a TLS1.3 requirement change. The code in this answer was written in 2012, and a lot has changed since then. The main code should still work, but you probably need to figure out new hashing and key usage OIDs. Maybe see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70278265/53538 and this (unrelated) answer: https://superuser.com/a/1466427/10942 . Personally I haven't touched Windows code in many years so I don't have the facilities to review and verify.

Answer (score 119):

Since .NET 4.7.2 you can create self-signed certs using [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netframework-4.7.2).

For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class CertificateUtil
{
    static void MakeCert()
    {
        var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair
        var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=foobar", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));

        // Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\temp\\mycert.pfx", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "P@55w0rd"));

        // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
        File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\mycert.cer",
            "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
            + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
            + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
    }
}
```

Comment: The cert doesn't seem to have a private key associated with it, is there a way to generated? I need to import the cert into the cert store for IIS.

Comment: @Viertaxa The PFX contains the private key - import that, not the CER file

Comment: I'm actually getting a null reference exception on cert.PrivateKey.Get(), as if the .CreateSelfSigned is not generating it. Interestingly, the .HasPrivateKey property returns true.

Comment: Update: It seems the .Export is critical. Once exporting to a byte array and re-importing to a new X509Certificate2, I was able to use the private key.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not available in .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: @Viertaxa how did exporting an re-importing work for you? For me its throwing, systemnotsupported exception on accessing private key..    
       
{var ecdsa = System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create();
            var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=test", ecdsa, System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            X509Certificate2 cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));
            X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "P@55w0rd"), "P@55w0rd", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);}

Comment: @GregVogel CreateSelfSigned function is supported in .Net Standard 2.1. Looks like a good answer

Comment: @Viertaxa Can you please post your code to get the private key?

Comment: @Viertaxa You can call `cert2.GetECDsaPrivateKey()` to get the private key.

Comment: @DuncanSmart The ecdsa and cert objects implement `IDisposable` and should be created in `using` statements.

Comment: Excellent answer, for anyone that is using the resulting pfx to sign JWT tokens using RSA in the request will work. `var request = new CertificateRequest($"CN={name}", RSA.Create(), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);`

Comment: For whatever reason only on .NET Framework, not .NET Core, was it giving me this null private key issue. Exporting and Importing worked, but only if I explicitly provided a password to the export/import (no/null password just kept giving the null private cert issue).

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to use the [CLR Security extensions library](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/clrsecurity) from CodePlex, which implements a helper function to generate self-signed X.509 certificates:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = CngKey.CreateSelfSignedCertificate(subjectName);
```

You can also look at the implementation of that function (in [`CngKeyExtensionMethods.cs`](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/clrsecurity/blob/master/Security.Cryptography/src/CngKeyExtensionMethods.cs)) to see how to create the self-signed certificate explicitly in managed code.

Comment: The CLR security work looks interesting - do you know what is the relationship between this project and Microsoft corporation? The project page seem to assert that it is written by the same team that wrote the standard Security.Cryptography classes, but I didn't see any reference to it other than a couple of blogs. Being a security software package, its important to know if it is subject to the same security review as the official .net release. What also doesn't help my gut feeling is that the last release is for .net 3.5 but the provided functionality is still missing from .net 4.x...

Comment: It was written by people who were on the CLR security team at Microsoft. I think the intent was to fold the extensions into a Microsoft .NET release at some point, but I don't think that has happened. You might ping shawnfa via the codeplex site to see where its at. He was my go-to guy with x509 questions when I was at Microsoft. He's really good with this crypto stuff.

Comment: What SHA is this using?

Comment: How can access to the private key?, when I try access I got an exception.

Answer (score 13):

If it helps anyone else, I needed to generate a test certificate in PEM format (so needed crt and key files), using the [answer from Duncan Smart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535184/843387), I produced the following...

```cs
public static void MakeCert(string certFilename, string keyFilename)
{
    const string CRT_HEADER = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
    const string CRT_FOOTER = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    const string KEY_HEADER = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    const string KEY_FOOTER = "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
    var certRequest = new CertificateRequest("cn=test", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    // We're just going to create a temporary certificate, that won't be valid for long
    var certificate = certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1));

    // export the private key
    var privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);

    File.WriteAllText(keyFilename, KEY_HEADER + privateKey + KEY_FOOTER);

    // Export the certificate
    var exportData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

    var crt = Convert.ToBase64String(exportData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    File.WriteAllText(certFilename, CRT_HEADER + crt + CRT_FOOTER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I needed an RSA certificate and this works well! I'm using a variation of this code for in-memory certificate creation to run in some unit tests.

Comment: This solution has solved the issue, that PrivateKey prop is `Null`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the free [PluralSight.Crypto library](http://blog.pluralsight.com/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net) to simplify programmatic creation of self-signed X.509 certificates:

```
    using (CryptContext ctx = new CryptContext())
    {
        ctx.Open();

        X509Certificate2 cert = ctx.CreateSelfSignedCertificate(
            new SelfSignedCertProperties
            {
                IsPrivateKeyExportable = true,
                KeyBitLength = 4096,
                Name = new X500DistinguishedName("cn=localhost"),
                ValidFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
                ValidTo = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1),
            });

        X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(cert);
    }
```

PluralSight.Crypto requires .NET 3.5 or later.

Comment: I up voter because its a solution, but please note that using PluralSight is a problem for several reasons:

(1) defining it is "free" is problematic - can I use it in my open source project and release its source code under the General Public License? Can I use it in my commercial product and sell software that includes it? For those unfamiliar with software licensing, the answer to these questions is **no**.

(2) Internally PluralSight uses P/Invoke, so if you have problems with using P/Invoke (other then not wanting to write it yourself), then you still have a problem.

Comment: I've generated certificate using this tool and chrome is complaining that for signature it is using SHA1, which is considered insecure.

Comment: @Guss Every file in the sources has a comment o top: `// This code was written by Keith Brown, and may be freely used.`

Comment: @gisek - I was referring to a page on PluralSight that offered the library for download (not as part of a sample project like the link in the answer) and the license there was problematic (I don't remember details). I can't find that page now (6 years later), nor can I find any official site for the library, so at this time I can only comment that "may be freely used" is a horrible license due to much of the same reasons that "public domain" doesn't work (see this article for details: https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/) but its probably good enough for most people.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [0909EMs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63561595/226278) with **SubjectAlternativeNames** based on code found here:  [Understanding self-signed certificates in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892761/understanding-self-signed-certificates-in-c-sharp)

```
        public static void MakeCert(string certFilename, string keyFilename)
        {
            const string CRT_HEADER = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
            const string CRT_FOOTER = "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

            const string KEY_HEADER = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
            const string KEY_FOOTER = "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

            using var rsa = RSA.Create();
            var certRequest = new CertificateRequest("cn=test", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            // Adding SubjectAlternativeNames (SAN)
            var subjectAlternativeNames = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
            subjectAlternativeNames .AddDnsName("test");
            certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(subjectAlternativeNames.Build());

            // We're just going to create a temporary certificate, that won't be valid for long
            var certificate = certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1));

            // export the private key
            var privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);

            File.WriteAllText(keyFilename, KEY_HEADER + privateKey + KEY_FOOTER);

            // Export the certificate
            var exportData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

            var crt = Convert.ToBase64String(exportData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
            File.WriteAllText(certFilename, CRT_HEADER + crt + CRT_FOOTER);
        }
```

And for definition of the usage of a key using `X509KeyUsageExtension` look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210587/226278

Answer (score 1):

Here is console app which will ask user hostname, expiry in days and password.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

Console.Write("Enter hostname: ");
string hostname = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter days until expiration: ");
int days = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter password, enter to skip: ");
string password = Console.ReadLine();

// Generate a new RSA key pair
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();

// Create a certificate request with the specified subject and key pair
CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest(
    $"CN={hostname}",
    rsa,
    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

// Create a self-signed certificate from the certificate request
X509Certificate2 certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(days));

// Export the certificate to a file with password
byte[] certBytes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) 
    ? certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx) 
    : certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);
File.WriteAllBytes($"{hostname}.pfx", certBytes);

Console.WriteLine($"Certificate for {hostname} created successfully and will expire on {certificate.NotAfter}.");
Console.WriteLine($"Path: {Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, hostname)}.pfx");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the Powershell version on how to create a certificate. You can use it by executing the command.
Check https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate

Edit: forgot to say that after you create the certificate, you can use the Windows "manage computer certificates" program, to export the certificate to .CER or other type.