# Issues compiling in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, certenroll

I have identified an issue related to building apps that use C:\Windows\System32\CertEnroll.dll as a reference.

The following code works fine when compiled using VS 2015 on Windows 7 and then ran on a Windows 7 machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CERTENROLLLib;

namespace CertTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CX509PrivateKey key = new CX509PrivateKey();
                key.ContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you try and compile this in Windows 10 and then try and run it on a Windows 7 machine, it throws the following error.

> "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'CERTENROLLLib.CX509PrivateKey'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{728AB362-217D-11DA-B2A4-000E7BBB2B09}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

I have had several people here replicate it and I'd like to get more input before contacting Microsoft on what's going on here.

I guess my question is:  Can anybody else confirm this or if it's confirmed they broke backward compatibilty?

Comment: Have you tried running this in both 64 bit and 32 bit mode? Looks like MS changed the interface significantly between the two.

Comment: So far my tests have only been x64

Comment: From an elevated command prompt, can you run `regsvr32 c:\Windows\System32\CertEnroll.dll` and see if that makes any difference? It could be because of a broken registration, otherwise try to run under 32 bit and see if you get the same error.

Comment: The .dll is registered fine.  The target machine will always be x64 and the application this is in must be compiled as x64.  The code is simply a snippet from that application.  If I had to guess, this issue has something to do with the ActiveX changes they did in Windows 10 but I thought those were only for Edge

Comment: I can confirm i am facing the same problem, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: I have same issue. do you get any solution?

Comment: Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the steps from Microsoft to resolve this issue

If you use Windows 10 solely as your build environment then the executable would run on downlevel OSes, however if you really just want to have a project that you can compile anywhere and run anywhere then the only solution is to create your own interop DLL that you include in the project folder.  You would have to generate it on Windows 7 first and reference that DLL.

Tlbimp.exe CertEnroll_Interop c:\Windows\System32\CertEnroll.dll

This generates a CertEnroll_Interop.dll file that you can copy to your project folder and then browse to in your project.  Of course you would need the using “using CertEnroll_Interop;” statement.

You can build the project on Windows 10 and have it run on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 and any other combination.

Comment: Note:You need to use the /out switch, i.e.
Tlbimp.exe /out:CertEnroll_Interop c:\Windows\System32\CertEnroll.dll

Otherwise it thinks CertEnroll_Interop is the type library name, and complains that it can't find it.

Answer (score 16):

Somehow the Interface Implementation on CertEnroll.dll changed between "vanilla" Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2. I guess it is the same with some Windows 7 builds. To get it (halfway) working, you have to instantiate the classes with `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(<TypeName>)`;
This will cause the system to look up the references in HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\ to get the right class for you.

## Working Example:

(Part of this code was used from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806300/5243037)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using CERTENROLLLib;


/// <summary>
///     Creates a self-signed certificate in the computer certificate store MY.
///     Issuer and Subject are computername and its domain.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="friendlyName">Friendly-name of the certificate</param>
/// <param name="password">Password which will be used by creation. I think it's obsolete...</param>
/// <returns>Created certificate</returns>
/// <remarks>Base from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806300/5243037 </remarks>
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string friendlyName, string password)
{
    // create DN for subject and issuer
    var dnHostName = new CX500DistinguishedName();
    // DN will be in format CN=machinename, DC=domain, DC=local for machinename.domain.local
    dnHostName.Encode(GetMachineDn());
    var dnSubjectName = dnHostName;

    //var privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
    var typeName = "X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey";
    var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeName);
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(typeName + " is not available on your system: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)");
    }
    var privateKey = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IX509PrivateKey;
    if (privateKey == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Your certlib does not know an implementation of " + typeName +
                            " (in HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Interface\\)!");
    }
    privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider";
    privateKey.ProviderType = X509ProviderType.XCN_PROV_RSA_AES;
    // key-bitness
    privateKey.Length = 2048;
    privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE;
    privateKey.MachineContext = true;
    // Don't allow export of private key
    privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_NONE;

    // use is not limited
    privateKey.Create();

    // Use the stronger SHA512 hashing algorithm
    var hashobj = new CObjectId();
    hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
        ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY,
        AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA512");

    // add extended key usage if you want - look at MSDN for a list of possible OIDs
    var oid = new CObjectId();
    oid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"); // SSL server
    var oidlist = new CObjectIds { oid };
    var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
    eku.InitializeEncode(oidlist);

    // add all IPs of current machine as dns-names (SAN), so a user connecting to our wcf 
    // service by IP still claim-trusts this server certificate
    var objExtensionAlternativeNames = new CX509ExtensionAlternativeNames();
    {
        var altNames = new CAlternativeNames();
        var dnsHostname = new CAlternativeName();
        dnsHostname.InitializeFromString(AlternativeNameType.XCN_CERT_ALT_NAME_DNS_NAME, Environment.MachineName);
        altNames.Add(dnsHostname);
        foreach (var ipAddress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
        {
            if ((ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork ||
                 ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) && !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ipAddress))
            {
                var dns = new CAlternativeName();
                dns.InitializeFromString(AlternativeNameType.XCN_CERT_ALT_NAME_DNS_NAME, ipAddress.ToString());
                altNames.Add(dns);
            }
        }
        objExtensionAlternativeNames.InitializeEncode(altNames);
    }

    // Create the self signing request
    //var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
    typeName = "X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestCertificate";
    type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeName);
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(typeName + " is not available on your system: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)");
    }
    var cert = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IX509CertificateRequestCertificate;
    if (cert == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Your certlib does not know an implementation of " + typeName +
                            " (in HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Interface\\)!");
    }
    cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, privateKey, "");
    cert.Subject = dnSubjectName;
    cert.Issuer = dnHostName; // the issuer and the subject are the same
    cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    // this cert expires immediately. Change to whatever makes sense for you
    cert.NotAfter = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku); // add the EKU
    cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionAlternativeNames);
    cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
    cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

    // Do the final enrollment process
    //var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
    typeName = "X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment";
    type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeName);
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(typeName + " is not available on your system: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)");
    }
    var enroll = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IX509Enrollment;
    if (enroll == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Your certlib does not know an implementation of " + typeName +
                            " (in HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Interface\\)!");
    }
    // Use private key to initialize the certrequest...
    enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert);
    enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = friendlyName; // Optional: add a friendly name
    var csr = enroll.CreateRequest(); // Output the request in base64 and install it back as the response
    enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate, csr,
        EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, password);

    // This will fail on Win2k8, some strange "Parameter is empty" error... Thus we search the
    // certificate by serial number with the managed X509Store-class
    // // output a base64 encoded PKCS#12 so we can import it back to the .Net security classes
    //var base64Encoded = enroll.CreatePFX(password, PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainNoRoot, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
    //return new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    var certFs = LoadCertFromStore(cert.SerialNumber);
    if (!certFs.HasPrivateKey) throw new InvalidOperationException("Created certificate has no private key!");

    return certFs;
}


/// <summary>
///     Converts Domain.local into CN=Domain, CN=local
/// </summary>
private static string GetDomainDn()
{
    var fqdnDomain = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fqdnDomain)) return null;
    var context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, fqdnDomain);
    var d = Domain.GetDomain(context);
    var de = d.GetDirectoryEntry();
    return de.Properties["DistinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
}

/// <summary>
///     Gets machine and domain name in X.500-format: CN=PC,DN=YourFirm,DN=local
/// </summary>
private static string GetMachineDn()
{
    var machine = "CN=" + Environment.MachineName;
    var dom = GetDomainDn();
    return machine + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dom) ? "" : ", " + dom);
}

/// <summary>
///     Load a certificate by serial number from computer.my-store
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serialNumber">Base64-encoded certificate serial number</param>
private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertFromStore(string serialNumber)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
    try
    {
        // serialnumber from certenroll.dll v6 is a base64 encoded byte array, which is reversed.
        // serialnumber from certenroll.dll v10 is a base64 encoded byte array, which is NOT reversed.
        var serialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(serialNumber);
        var serial = BitConverter.ToString(serialBytes.ToArray()).Replace("-", "");
        var serialReversed = BitConverter.ToString(serialBytes.Reverse().ToArray()).Replace("-", "");

        var serverCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, false);
        if (serverCerts.Count == 0)
        {
            serverCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialReversed, false);
        }
        if (serverCerts.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("No certificate with serial number <" + serial + "> or reversed serial <" + serialReversed + "> found!");
        }
        if (serverCerts.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Found multiple certificates with serial <" + serial + "> or reversed serial <" + serialReversed + ">!");
        }

        return serverCerts[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

## Remarks

So why did I write "halfway"? There is a problem with certenroll.dll V. 6, which causes the build to fail on cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey. In certenroll.dll V 6.0, the second parameter must be of type "CX509PrivateKey", whereas on Win10 machines with Certenroll.dll V 10, it's IX509PrivateKey:

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'CERTENROLLLib.IX509PrivateKey' to 'CERTENROLLLib.CX509PrivateKey'

So you would think: Yea, simply "cast" the privateKey in the above example to CX509PrivateKey on Activator.CreateInstance. The Problem here is, it will compile, but on vanilla Win2k8 it will not give you the class (CX509...) but the Interface (IX509...), and thus the cast fails and returns null.

We've solved this issue by compiling the certenrollment function in a seperate project on a machine with certenroll.dll V 10. It compiles fine and works in Win2k8, too. It's never-the-less a bit annoying to have it in a seperate project, since the build will fail on our buildserver with certenroll.dll V 6.

Comment: Where does GetMachineDN come from?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, my development machine is running on windows 10 and the build server windows 8.1.

But since c# has the ability of reflection and dynamic types, i now first analyze which types the *InitializeFromPrivateKey* method takes as parameters(I separated it from the actually certificate code by creating a method).

```
    private static bool IsCompiledOnWin10AndAbove()
    {
        var typeOfMethod = typeof(IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10);
        var methodType = typeOfMethod.GetMethod("InitializeFromPrivateKey", new Type[] { typeof(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext), typeof(CX509PrivateKey), typeof(string) });
        var methodeParameters = methodType.GetParameters();
        return methodeParameters[1].ParameterType != typeof(CX509PrivateKey);
    }
```

And then use a dynamic type dependent on which type the second parameter is.

```
        dynamic privateKeyCorrectType;
        if (IsCompiledOnWin10AndAbove()) // win 10 and above compiled
        {
            privateKeyCorrectType= privateKey;
        }
        else // below win 10 compiled
        {
            privateKeyCorrectType= (CX509PrivateKey)privateKey;
        }
        cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, privateKeyCorrectType, "");
```