# C# generate Self Signed Cert with Subject Alternative Name?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

We have an app that generates a Self Signed Cert but now with Chrome 58 we need to add the Subject Alternative Name.  The Cert is generated using C# but invoking the CertCreateSelfSignCertificate function in win32.  So far all the examples I am finding are not passing the extensions param and I'm finding it hard to create an extension to pass to generate the SAN.

**Note I will be cleaning this up once I get it working**
This is what I am using to create an Entry and then the Extension:

```
CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY entry = new CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY {
        dwAltNameChoice = AlternativeNameType.Dns, // 3
        Name = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("127.0.0.1")
    };
    IntPtr entryBlob Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY)));
    var pvStructInfo = new CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO { cAltEntry = 1, rgAltEntry = entryBlob };

            IntPtr pvEncoded = IntPtr.Zero;
            int pcbEncoded = 0;

            var status = InvokeMethods.CryptEncodeObjectEx(
                   CertEncodingType.X509_ASN_ENCODING | CertEncodingType.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,  // 1 | 0x10000
                   new IntPtr(12),
                   ref pvStructInfo,
                   EncodeObjectFlags.CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, // 0x8000
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   ref pvEncoded,
                   ref pcbEncoded);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(entryBlob);

            if (!status)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            var extension = new CERT_EXTENSION
            {
                ExtensionOid = OidSubjectAltName, //2.5.29.17
                IsCritical = false,
                Value = new CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
                {
                    Length = (uint)pcbEncoded,
                    Data = pvEncoded
                }
            };
            var result = new CertExtensions
            {
                cExtension = 1,
                rgExtension = extension
            };
```

**Structs Used**

```
internal struct CertExtensions
        {
            public uint cExtension;
            public CERT_EXTENSION rgExtension;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
        {
            public uint Length;
            public IntPtr Data;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal class CERT_EXTENSION
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string ExtensionOid;

            public bool IsCritical;
            public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Value;
        }

  [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO
        {
            /// DWORD->unsigned int
            public uint cAltEntry;

            public IntPtr rgAltEntry;
        }

        [StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY
        {
            public AlternativeNameType dwAltNameChoice;
            public IntPtr Name;
        }
```

**Full Code - Pieced together from a few examples I found**

```
private static CertExtensions CreateExtensions(IList<CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY> items)
        {

            IntPtr itemBlob = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(items.Count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY)));

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                var offset = (IntPtr)((long)itemBlob + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY)));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], offset, false);
            }

            var pvStructInfo = new CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO { cAltEntry = (uint)items.Count, rgAltEntry = itemBlob };

            IntPtr pvEncoded = IntPtr.Zero;
            int pcbEncoded = 0;

            var status = InvokeMethods.CryptEncodeObjectEx(
                   CertEncodingType.X509_ASN_ENCODING | CertEncodingType.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                   new IntPtr(12),
                   ref pvStructInfo,
                   EncodeObjectFlags.CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG,
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   ref pvEncoded,
                   ref pcbEncoded);


            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(itemBlob);

            if (!status)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            var extension = new CERT_EXTENSION
            {
                ExtensionOid = OidSubjectAltName,
                IsCritical = false,
                Value = new CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
                {
                    Length = (uint)pcbEncoded,
                    Data = pvEncoded
                }
            };
            var result = new CertExtensions
            {
                cExtension = 1,
                rgExtension = extension
            };

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Actually, the function supports extensions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376039(v=vs.85).aspx there is `pExtensions` parameter that accepts a pointer to a an array of certificate extensions.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but being a primarily C# developer I am trying to find a full example of how to implement this.  I have pushed as far as being able to create the Cert_Extensions with one Cert_Extension added successfully but now I'm getting  a "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." which I'm assuming means something isn't being either released correctly or encoded correctly.  I have found many examples of using CerCreateSelfSignCertificate but passing a null or 0 for extensions param.

Comment: are you looking for alternative DNS names in SAN extension?

Comment: Sure am.  I am very close I believe but am still missing something.  When creating the CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO and the CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY I verified I'm using the DNS for AlternativeNameType (3) and the correct length for the CryptEncodeObjectEx function for the lpszStructType param.

Comment: maybe you post some piece of code in your posting? Need to understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I added the code snippet. If I zero out the extensions param from CertCreateSelfSignCertification it goes through just fine, so I know it has to do with the extensions variable.

Comment: Looks like `CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY` has invalid signature. And `CertExtensions` as well. Post them. In addition, you are allocating `entryBlob` buffer, but don't use it. In the provided code you allocate and release, but do not use it.

Comment: I added the structs.  Also, I pulled the code out so that I could show how I was creating the CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY.  The code that I'm really using is a collection of CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY and it loops through.  This is where I think the issue is because I don't know enough about Windows allocating memory and marshaling.  This isn't my area. At the bottom is what I'm using and the array is of the one ALT_CERT_NAME_ENTRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this going to be a hell of C#/C++ interop and is hard to understand without knowing how pointers, structs and C-like arrays work in C++ and how marshalong works in interop.

You have incorrectly defined `CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY` structure. It used `union` in C++ definition. When translating unions to C# they must be aligned to the largest struct size in union (which is `CRYPTOAPI_BLOB` and which is 8 bytes) and plus other field size: 8 + 4 = 12 bytes. Your struct signature is only 8 bytes.

`rgExtension` member in `CERT_EXTENSIONS` structure doesn't accept single `CERT_EXTENSION` struct, actually it is a pointer to an array of `CERT_EXTENSION` structs. This means that `rgExtension` member must be defined as `IntPtr`.

**Solution:**

Drop your entire code and use examples below.

Correct struct signature definitions:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestApp {
    static class Wincrypt {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
            public UInt32 cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]    
        public struct CERT_EXTENSION {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pszObjId;
            public Boolean fCritical;
            public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Value;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CERT_EXTENSIONS {
            public UInt32 cExtension;
            public IntPtr rgExtension;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO {
            public UInt32 cAltEntry;
            public IntPtr rgAltEntry;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY {
            public UInt32 dwAltNameChoice;
            // since there is no direct translation from C-like unions in C#
            // make additional struct to represent union options.
            public CERT_ALT_NAME_UNION Value;
        }
        // create mapping to dwAltNameChoice
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_OTHER_NAME = 1;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_RFC822_NAME = 2;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_DNS_NAME = 3;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_X400_ADDRESS = 4;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_DIRECTORY_NAME = 5;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_EDI_PARTY_NAME = 6;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_URL = 7;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS = 8;
        public const UInt32 CERT_ALT_NAME_REGISTERED_ID = 9;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CERT_ALT_NAME_UNION {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr pOtherName;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr pwszRfc822Name;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr pwszDNSName;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB DirectoryName;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr pwszURL;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr IPAddress;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public IntPtr pszRegisteredID;
        }
        // not really used in this scenario, but is necessary when want to add
        // UPN alt name, for example.
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CERT_OTHER_NAME {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pszObjId;
            public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Value;
        }
    }
}
```

`CryptEncodeObject` signature (haven't tried Ex version):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestApp {
    static class Crypt32 {
        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptEncodeObject(
            [In] UInt32 CertEncodingType,
            [In] UInt32 lpszStructType,
            [In, Out]ref Wincrypt.CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO pvStructInfo,
            [Out] Byte[] pbEncoded,
            [In, Out] ref UInt32 cbEncoded);
    }
}
```

and the whole story with comments:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            //return;
            // suppose we want to add three alternative DNS names to SAN extension
            String[] dnsNames = { "contoso.com", "www.contoso.com", "mail.contoso.com" };
            // calculate size of CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY structure. Since it is C-like
            // struct, use Marshal.SizeOf(), not C# sizeof().
            var altEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wincrypt.CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY));
            // create CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO structure and set initial data:
            // cAltEntry -- number of alt names in the extension
            // rgAltEntry -- starting pointer in unmanaged memory to an array of alt names
            // the size is calculated as: CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY size * alt name count
            var altInfo = new Wincrypt.CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO {
                cAltEntry = (UInt32)dnsNames.Length,
                rgAltEntry = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(altEntrySize * dnsNames.Length)
            };
            // now create CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY for each alt name and copy structure to
            // a pointer allocated in altInfo structure with a shift.
            // Create a loop to save some coding
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < dnsNames.Length; i++) {
                var altEntry = new Wincrypt.CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY {
                    dwAltNameChoice = Wincrypt.CERT_ALT_NAME_DNS_NAME,
                    // use Uni, because the pwszDNSName is defined as LPWStr (unicode)
                    Value = { pwszDNSName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(dnsNames[i]) },
                };
                // copy alt name entry to altInfo.rgAltEntry at the specified index.
                // In unmanaged memory you have to calculate shift based on managed
                // index and structure size
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(altEntry, altInfo.rgAltEntry + i * altEntrySize, false);
            }
            // encode CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO to ASN.1 DER byte array
            UInt32 pcbEncoded = 0;
            if (Crypt32.CryptEncodeObject(1, 12, ref altInfo, null, ref pcbEncoded)) {
                Byte[] encodedSANvalue = new Byte[pcbEncoded];
                Crypt32.CryptEncodeObject(1, 12, ref altInfo, encodedSANvalue, ref pcbEncoded);
                // create certificate extension array:
                var extensions = new Wincrypt.CERT_EXTENSIONS {
                    cExtension = 1,
                    rgExtension = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Wincrypt.CERT_EXTENSION)))
                };
                // create SAN extension:
                var san = new Wincrypt.CERT_EXTENSION {
                    fCritical = false,
                    pszObjId = "2.5.29.17",
                    Value = { cbData = (UInt32)encodedSANvalue.Length, pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(encodedSANvalue.Length) }
                };
                // copy SAN bytes to SAN extension:
                Marshal.Copy(encodedSANvalue,0,san.Value.pbData, encodedSANvalue.Length);
                // copy CERT_EXTENSION structure to extensions:
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(san, extensions.rgExtension, false);
                // use 'extensions' variable in CertCreateSelfSignCertificate call.
            } else {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One note: the provided code do not release unmanaged resources. You have to release them after calling `CertCreateSelfSignCertificate` function.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I understand most of it.  The only two lines I'm not clear on what they are exactly doing are these:  `code` // copy SAN bytes to SAN extension:
                Marshal.Copy(encodedSANvalue, 0, san.Value.pbData, encodedSANvalue.Length);
                // copy CERT_EXTENSION structure to extensions:
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(san, extensions.rgExtension, true); `code`  The app is failing on the second line at this point.  On fail it just kicks me out of debug completely.

Comment: To clarify, I read what they are doing but not sure why it would fail other than maybe permissions on my machine?

Comment: I updated the code, now it should work. I changed last parameter in `Marshal.StructureToPtr` call to `false`. This parameter sometimes causes such issues.

Comment: After SAN value is encoded, encoded bytes must be passed to `CERT_EXTENSION` object as a value (simply attatch). Then we have to get a pointer to `CERT_EXTENSION` object in order to add it to a unmanaged array. Natively, array in memory is just a sequence of pointers where each pointer points to an object associated with the current element. C-style arrays are not the same as C# in syntax.

Comment: Thank you!  I already tried the "false" param and then it didn't choke however I'm still getting the "Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." error when calling CertCreateSelfSignCertificate.  Your code makes more sense and I appreciate it, but I'm back to where I was before.  I will hammer  back on this tomorrow.

Comment: I was finally able to get this working by changing the struct for the CertCreateSelfSignCertificate to use an IntPtr instead of CERT_EXTENSIONS and made sure I released before calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I had a similar requirement, To Create a Self-Signed SSL Cert for Kestral in C# dotnet core.  This is what I've gotten working:

```
    .ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
    {
        serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.ServerCertificate = GetOrAddSelfSigned("cn=MyCert", StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        });
    })
```

...

```
    private static X509Certificate2 GetOrAddSelfSigned(string subjectName, StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation)
    {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        using (var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            var cert = (from X509Certificate2 c in store.Certificates
                        where c.Subject.Equals(subjectName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        where c.NotBefore <= now && now < c.NotAfter
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cert == null)
            {
                using (var key = RSA.Create(2048))
                {
                    var request = new CertificateRequest(subjectName, key, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                        new X509KeyUsageExtension(
                            X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature,
                            critical: false));

                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                        new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                            new OidCollection
                            {
                                new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"),
                            },
                            critical: false));

                    var san = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
                    san.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Loopback);
                    san.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback);
                    san.AddDnsName("localhost");
                    san.AddDnsName(Environment.MachineName);
                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(san.Build());

                    var password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    cert = request.CreateSelfSigned(now.AddMinutes(-4), now.AddYears(1));
                    cert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }

            return cert;
        }
```

Largely adapted from:

[How to create a valid, self-signed X509Certificate2 programmatically, not loading from file in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786986/how-to-create-a-valid-self-signed-x509certificate2-programmatically-not-loadin)