# Extract data (IP adresses) from X509Certificate2 in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2, .net-core-2.2

I am just curious and experimenting with certificates in .NET Core. I am doing this to get a better understanding of the certificates I use (or should use) in .NET Core (e.g. data protection etc...)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786986/how-to-create-a-valid-self-signed-x509certificate2-programmatically-not-loadin) showed a way to create a certificate by code.

I played around with it ended writing a cert file logging function returning me the contents of the certificate.

The code from the question sets ip adresses.

```
SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
    sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Loopback);
    sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback);
    sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost");
    sanBuilder.AddDnsName(Environment.MachineName);
```

Now there is a created X509Certificate2 with some IP adresses set but I don't find a way to get this information from the created certificate.

I also haven't found any tool showing these values.

How do I read them in order to confirm they are there?

I am trying to log all the data in a certificate and the IP addresses seem to be part of it?

Comment: @Amy yes, this returns the values I was looking for.