# How to use tsl version 1.0 in C# server?

Tags: c#, ssl, server

Welcome, Im interesting in creating my own local service, witch support TSL v1 only.

I know its weak. But some app does not allow use modern cert above 1.0... 
This app has no update to long, and just update it to TSL 1.3/1.2 is impossible.

There two question in complex.

1. How to create self-signed cert (private and public key) v1.0
2. How to use this cert in C#, im binding loop back address.

maybe soft like makecert/openssl can help? Which crypt-algorithm i should to use?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for .NET Core 2.0 and above.

This guide [Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it is a guide to create a server.

The certificate and TLS version can be configured in Kestrel server HTTPS defauls:

```
app.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls;
        listenOptions.ServerCertificate = x509Certificate2; // instance of X509Certificate2
    });

});
```

The value `SslProtocols.Tls` specifies TLS 1.0 security protocol.

How to create a valid, self-signed, `X509Certificate2`, needed in the code above, is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786986/how-to-create-a-valid-self-signed-x509certificate2-programmatically-not-loadin). Certificates API was added to .Net Core on 2.0 version.