# Trouble signing a JWT token with an x509 Certificate

Tags: c#, jwt, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I'm having trouble signing a JWT token with a certificate that I created.  I understand the fundamentals of how signing (public/private key) works, but the classes and toolsets are very confusing.  I've been fussing with this example code for quite a while, and I'm fully stuck now.  When I run the attached example code I end up with the following error (on the `tokenHandler.CreateToken()` call):

> System.NotSupportedException: 'IDX10634: Unable to create the
>   SignatureProvider. Algorithm: '[PII is hidden]', SecurityKey: '[PII is
>   hidden]'  is not supported.'

I've provided the certificate I created in the **CertificatePfxFileBase64Encoded** variable base64 encoded.  It's a .pfx file with the private key embedded in it with no password.  Its a binary file so I had to base64 encoded in order to share it here.  I'm trying to get a good understanding of how these classes work but I can't get past this hurdle.  Any ideas?  The example below should be fully self contained, you just have to gather the references.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace SecurityStuff
{
    public class Testing
    {
        static string CertificatePfxFileBase64Encoded = @"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";

        public static string CreateTokenWithX509SigningCredentials()
        {
            var signingCert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(CertificatePfxFileBase64Encoded));

            var privateKey = new X509SecurityKey(signingCert);
            var algo = privateKey.PrivateKey.SignatureAlgorithm;
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateKey, algo);

            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                        {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "John"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Sales"),
                        }),
                Issuer = "self",
                IssuedAt = now,
                NotBefore = now,
                Expires = now.AddMinutes(50),
                //SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(signingCert),     //For some reason this class no longer exists
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            string tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return tokenString;
        }
    }
}
```

**==== EDIT ====**

I thought it might be helpful to show how I made the signing certificate because maybe the problem lies in there.  Below are the command lines I used to generate my certificate **CertificatePfxFileBase64Encoded**.  I used the application [openSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) to generate it.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout CA_PrivateKey.key -out CA_SigningRequest.csr 

openssl x509 -req -days 2000 -in CA_SigningRequest.csr -signkey CA_PrivateKey.key -out CA_Certificate.crt 

openssl pkcs12 -export -out CA_Certificate.pfx -inkey CA_Private.key -in CA_Certificate.crt
```

Comment: FYI, generation of the pfx certificate can be done using RSA and the c# code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806299/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-c#answer-52535184)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code generates a JWT token from a .pfx file.

```
public static string GenerateToken(int expireMinutes)
{
    X509Certificate2 signingCert = new X509Certificate2("PFXFilePath", "password");
    X509SecurityKey privateKey = new X509SecurityKey(signingCert);
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)
    };
    JwtSecurityToken stoken = (JwtSecurityToken)tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);
    return token;
}
```

Comment: If I paste the generated JWT into https://jwt.io/ it tells me it has an invalid signature. The PFX file I use was generated from OpenSSL, and I was able to import it into the Windows certificate store, so it is valid. Has this process changed for .NET 7.0?