# Generate base-64 encoded X509 certificate pair (public/private

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to generate RSA X509 public/private key to dynamically,
below is how I do it with openssh command line:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 1825
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in publickey.cer
```

Also how do I add passphrase to encrypt the private key?

and I only got here by far

```
//Generate a public/private key pair.  
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

//Save the public key information to an RSAParameters structure.  
RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

I have used [this](https://gist.github.com/ststeiger/f4b29a140b1e3fd618679f89b7f3ff4a) class however it does not result into a valid SSL, when I submit it to developer portal it did not get accepted as valid public key: developer.xero.com/myapps

Regards

Comment: Clarification needed: do you want to create certificate from RSAParameters alone?

Comment: Please educate me what are the params, I am not sure if there are other parameters missing in standard X509 format? I need to do what openssl does in command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I have replaced the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class with the recommended `RSA` base class which is cross-platform and also the [better RSA implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-portal).

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806299/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-c) put me in the right direction.

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create(1024))
{
    var distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN=SelfSignedCertificate");
    var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1825));

    // Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key
    File.WriteAllBytes("privatekey.pfx", certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "RGliXtaLkENste"));

    // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
    File.WriteAllText("publickey.cer",
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
}
```

I have tested the resulting `.cer` file on xero so it should work

Comment: I have used this class however it does not result into a valid SSL, when I submit it to developer portal it did not get accepted as valid public key: https://developer.xero.com/myapps/

Comment: @Mason.Chase I have updated my answer to generate a `.cer` and a `.pfx` file, I have also uploaded the `.cer` file to a demo xero app

Comment: Hi Elphas, thanks for the answer, how do I export private key in PEM format?

Comment: @Mason.Chase You would need to export the parameters from the RSA provider and use the algorithms I added in previous edits to produce the PEM file. I'll add back the methods to generate the file at some point.