# Java 8 open windows custom csp provider and retrieve key

Tags: java, hsm, mscapi

I am trying to find a way to load HSM key stored in Utimaco HSM CSP from JAVA

So far I got leads from search that it would be possible with SunMscApi provider, but I cant find any example where I would specify `Utimaco CryptoServer CSP` as provider ?crypto context? and container name `TEST_CSP_HSM`. The only examples I found were to load certificate from Windows-My keystore, but its not there.

[image: Utimaco CSP tool]

```
$ cngtool ListKeys

------------------------------------------------------------

Provider          : Utimaco CryptoServer Key Storage Provider
Device            : 3001@127.0.0.1
Group             : CNG
Mode              : Internal Key Storage

------------------------------------------------------------

Index  AlgId        Size   Group            Name                             Spec
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      RSA          2048   CNG              TEST_CSP_HSM                     2
```

Comment: This is working .NET code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806300/6197785
it might help you understand what you need to look for,
*note: sha512 doesn't work with all providers, you may need sha1 with them

Comment: Are you looking to just manually access the key file for some non-standard usage, or you really just want to use the HSM from Java?

Comment: Will a PKCS#11 solution make sense for you?

Comment: @jccampanero no

Answer (score 1):

The MSCAPI provider enables application access to Window-Store with two option: **"Windows-MY"** and **"Windows-ROOT"**, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI

For the **Windows-MY** it only access to Current-User, can not access to Local-Machine. Therefore, solution for this problem is we try to add certificate of HSM Utimaco into Current-User of Window-Store.

To check where is the certificate of HSM Utimaco: Run -> mmc -> File -> Add/Remove SnapIn -> Select "Certificate" -> Add -> Select "My user account" to view the Current-User (Select "Computer account" to view the Local-Machine)
[image]

To add the certificate of HSM Utimaco into Current-User:

```
certutil -user -addstore My path-to-cert.cer
certutil -f -csp "Utimaco CryptoServer CSP" -repairstore My "{thumbprint-of-cert}"
```

Comment: But there is only private key stored in CSP container, there is no certificate

Comment: You can self-signed a certificate for your key-pair.

Comment: bounty auto awarded, but not earned